# Does gensim use Negative sampling in Word2vec?

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, word2vec, gensim

When I train a word2vec model in Gensim on a huge amount of words/data (let's say hundreds of thousands of word vectors), is gensim using **negative sampling** automatically?

Alternatively, is there a way to make it use it?

Answer (score 2):

Gensim's word2vec can use negative sampling. When calling `class gensim.models.word2vec.Word2Vec`, there is a parameter `negative`. The default amount is `negative=5`.

> negative (int, optional) – If > 0, negative sampling will be used, the int for negative specifies how many “noise words” should be drawn (usually between 5-20). If set to 0, no negative sampling is used.

The documentation is [here](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/word2vec.html).

Comment: Please correct me if I'm wrong: the default is the number of 'negative' observations sampled for the logistic regression, right?